# Assistant Editor locked in Xcode

Tags: ios, macos, storyboard, xib, xcode11

From last two days, I am able to open the assistant editor and when I opened my other projects they were also having the same error.

Also, the new ones that I made, had the same error. Therefore, I am able to establish a connection between view controller and storyboard, and there was a lock icon on the side of the assistant editor that I tried to open.

When I tried to unlock the lock icon it showed:

[image]

The file is a remote resource. Try making a local copy.

I have deleted derived data also but didn't get any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xcode IDE default setting change to false use the below step:

1. Close the Xcode
2. Open the terminal
3. Add this cmd `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable -bool false` then press enter
4. Close the terminal
5. Restart the system
6. Run the Xcode and check all the thing working fine

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I am having the same Problem. But, I have it working in my other projects. I have used your method but, it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can see my problem on https://stackoverflow.com/q/63130019/13218692

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 Please follow the above instruction

Comment: Be sure to restart your computer.